# How to detect that you're in a test environment (check / determine if tests are being run)

Tags: django, unit-testing, test-environments

How can I detect whether a view is being called in a test environment (e.g., from `manage.py test`)?

```
#pseudo_code
def my_view(request):
    if not request.is_secure() and not TEST_ENVIRONMENT:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: What attributes does `request` have? Is there any indication in there?

Comment: When you say 'test environment', do you mean 'while running tests'? If so, why on Earth would you want to do this? Special-casing code that only works while you're running tests means that you're not actually testing your real code at all, so what's the point?

Comment: it's worth noting, you could create a `@https_only` wrapper for secure views, instead of using manual logic in your views. In `https_only` you can send a redirect using `https` when needed, or raise your exception there.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Put this in your settings.py:

```
import sys

TESTING = len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'test'
```

This tests whether the second commandline argument (after `./manage.py`) was `test`. Then you can access this variable from other modules, like so:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.TESTING:
    ...
```

There are good reasons to do this: suppose you're accessing some backend service, other than Django's models and DB connections. Then you might need to know when to call the production service vs. the test service.

Comment: What if there is some management command which requires the parameter `test` to be put in sys.argv?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini in that case you can be more specific and require it to be the 2nd argument (after manage.py): `TESTING = len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'test'`

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing and I would suggest to do in general.

Comment: That's a fragile hack, what about someone using nose or py.test to run tests ?

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande I don't know what nose or py.test are. Any patches are welcome.

Comment: @Tobia they are alternate test runners, broadly used see https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and http://pytest.org/latest/ I don't want to patch, I think the approach of looking at argv is not robust and universal enough. Other solutions are best suited IMHO (like travis-jensen rednaw or pymarco).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right answer, but it might take the problem of knowing in which position the test parameter goes: <code>TESTING='test' in sys.argv

Answer (score 24):

Create your own TestSuiteRunner subclass and change a setting or do whatever else you need to for the rest of your application. You specify the test runner in your settings:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'your.project.MyTestSuiteRunner'
```

In general, you don't want to do this, but it works if you absolutely need it.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner

class MyTestSuiteRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        settings.IM_IN_TEST_MODE = True
        super(MyTestSuiteRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Seems like the only solution here that doesn't rely on knowing some variable value, like sys.argv or the name of the test server...

Comment: While it's good to have different solutions to the problem, changing django settings at runtime doesn't seem a wise choice

Comment: This is the most stable, universal and flexible solution. But django.test.simple is deprecated. Should use now from django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner as parent class for test runner

Comment: Also it is better to change settings in `setup_test_environment` method instead of `__init__`

Comment: In Django 1.8+, use `from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner as DjangoTestSuiteRunner`

Answer (score 15):

Just look at `request.META['SERVER_NAME']`

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.META['SERVER_NAME'] == "testserver":
        print "This is test environment!"
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on something that an attacker can have access to, I assume this is somehow configurable through headers and could be manipulated to make believe the origin is from a test suite when it would actually be something external

Answer (score 9):

There's also a way to temporarily overwrite settings in a unit test in Django. This might be a easier/cleaner solution for certain cases.

You can do this inside a test:

```
with self.settings(MY_SETTING='my_value'):
    # test code
```

Or add it as a decorator on the test method:

```
@override_settings(MY_SETTING='my_value')
def test_my_test(self):
    # test code
```

You can also set the decorator for the whole test case class:

```
@override_settings(MY_SETTING='my_value')
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    # test methods
```

For more info check the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings

Comment: I tried all 3 of these methods on django 2.2 and none appear to work (EDIT: until I realized I was importing myapp.settings instead of django.conf.settings).

Answer (score 7):

I think the best approach is to run your tests using their own settings file (i.e. settings/tests.py). That file can look like this (the first line imports settings from a local.py settings file):

```
from local import *
TEST_MODE = True
```

Then do ducktyping to check if you are in test mode.

```
try:
    if settings.TEST_MODE:
        print 'foo'
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are multiple settings file for different environment, all you need to do is to create one settings file for testing.

For instance, your setting files are:

```
your_project/
      |_ settings/
           |_ __init__.py
           |_ base.py  <-- your original settings
           |_ testing.py  <-- for testing only
```

In your testing.py, add a `TESTING` flag:

```
from .base import *

TESTING = True
```

In your application, you can access `settings.TESTING` to check if you're in testing environment.

To run tests, use:

```
python manage.py test --settings your_project.settings.testing
```

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking off of @Tobia's answer, I think it is better implemented in settings.py like this:

```
import sys
try:
    TESTING = 'test' == sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    TESTING = False
```

This will prevent it from catching things like `./manage.py loaddata test.json` or `./manage.py i_am_not_running_a_test`

Comment: This is not very flexible as the `test` argument can be on another index. E.g. run as `python manage.py test` it's at index 2.

Comment: @gertvdijk then change it to `'test' == sys.argv[2]` :)

Comment: @glarrain Of course, but my point is, that you don't know it on beforehand as it depends on how the user invokes the test runner.

Comment: "This will prevent it from catching things like `./manage.py loaddata test.json`". That command wouldn't cause `'test' in sys.argv` to be true anyway since `'test' in ['./manage.py', 'loaddata', 'test.json'] == False`.

Comment: All of this is `False` in Tobia's answer either.

Answer (score 2):

While there's no official way to see whether we're in a test environment, django actually leaves some clues for us. 
By default Django’s test runner  [automatically redirects all Django-sent email to a dummy outbox](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#email-services). This is accomplished by replacing [EMAIL_BACKEND](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_BACKEND) in a function called [setup_test_environment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.utils.setup_test_environment), which in turn is called by a [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner.setup_test_environment) of DiscoverRunner. So, we can check whether settings.EMAIL_BACKEND is set to 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'. That mean we're in a test environment.

A less hacky solution would be following the devs lead by adding our own setting by subclassing DisoverRunner and then overriding setup_test_environment method.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to exclude some data migrations from being run in tests, and came up with this solution on a Django 3.2 project:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        import inspect
        if 'create_test_db' in [i.function for i in inspect.stack()]:
            return project_state
        else:
            return super().apply(project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=collect_sql)
```

I haven't seen this suggested elsewhere, and for my purposes it's pretty clean. Of course, it might break if Django changes the name of the `create_test_db` method (or the return value of the `apply` method) at some point in time, but modifying this to work should be reasonably simple, since it's likely that some method exists in the stack that doesn't exist during non-test migration runs.