# How do you set DEBUG to True when running a Django test?

Tags: django

I'm currently running some Django tests and it looks that `DEBUG=False` by default.  Is there a way to run a specific test where I can set `DEBUG=True` at the command line or in code?

Comment: According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#other-test-conditions, test set `DEBUG=False`.  I was looking for a way to bypass that.  Even if I pass `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`, it will revert to `False` while running tests.

Comment: Never mind, I can set `settings.DEBUG = True` under `setUp`

Comment: "Regardless of the value of the DEBUG setting in your configuration file, all Django tests run with DEBUG=False." [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions)

Answer (score 108):

For a specific test inside a test case, you can use the override_settings decorator:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from django.conf import settings
class TestSomething(TestCase):
    @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
    def test_debug(self):
        assert settings.DEBUG
```

Comment: As of Django 1.8, selnium 2.48.0 this worked for me.

Comment: You can also override the setting for the entire test class. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings

Comment: correct link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings

Comment: Doesn't work if `urlpatterns` is constructed based on `settings.DEBUG`.

Answer (score 38):

[Starting with Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-debug-mode) you can use `--debug-mode` to set the DEBUG setting to True prior to running tests.

Comment: I have a case similar to Abhimanyu's answer (with `urlpatterns`). This actually works, but none of the other answers work.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I use Selenium for testing, and setting `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)` makes the test browser always display `404` error on every page. And `DEBUG=False` does not show exception tracebacks. So I found a workaround.

The idea is to emulate `DEBUG=True` behaviour, using custom `500` handler and built-in django `500` error handler.

1. Add this to *myapp.views:*

   ```
   import sys
   from django import http
   from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter

   def show_server_error(request):
       """
       500 error handler to show Django default 500 template
       with nice error information and traceback.
       Useful in testing, if you can't set DEBUG=True.

       Templates: `500.html`
       Context: sys.exc_info() results
        """
       exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
       error = ExceptionReporter(request, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
       return http.HttpResponseServerError(error.get_traceback_html())
   ```
2. *urls.py:*

   ```
   from django.conf import settings

   if settings.TESTING_MODE:
       # enable this handler only for testing, 
       # so that if DEBUG=False and we're not testing,
       # the default handler is used
       handler500 = 'myapp.views.show_server_error'
   ```
3. *settings.py:*

   ```
   # detect testing mode
   import sys
   TESTING_MODE = 'test' in sys.argv
   ```

Now if any of your Selenium tests encounters 500 error, you'll see a nice error page with traceback and everything. If you run a normal non-testing environment, default 500 handler is used.

Inspired by:

- [Where in django is the default 500 traceback rendered so that I can use it to create my own logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924746/where-in-django-is-the-default-500-traceback-rendered-so-that-i-can-use-it-to-cr)
- [django - how to detect test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088253/django-how-to-detect-test-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's say you want to write tests for error testcase for which the urls are :-

**urls.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^404/$', page_not_found_view),
        url(r'^500/$', my_custom_error_view),
        url(r'^400/$', bad_request_view),
        url(r'^403/$', permission_denied_view),
    ]
```

**test_urls.py**:-

```
from django.conf import settings

class ErroCodeUrl(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        settings.DEBUG = True

    def test_400_error(self):
        response = self.client.get('/400/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)
```

**Hope you got some idea!**

Comment: @override_settings should be used to "unwind" the change before the next test.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work (Django 3.2). Even `override_settings(DEBUG=True)` doesn't work in this case. What does work is the `--debug-mode` flag that was suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me except https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118271/5750078
Use Python 3.7

```
breakpoint()
```

method.
Works fine on pycharm

Comment: This question is about how to set/ override a specific Django setting - in this case DEBUG - when running unit tests. Your qnswer and the link to the discussion you provided is about debugging.

Answer (score 0):

version 4.2
set an env variable

```
DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/logging/#examples

Answer (score -4):

You can't see the results of `DEBUG=True` when running a unit test.  The pages don't display anywhere.  No browser.

Changing `DEBUG` has no effect, since the web pages (with the debugging output) are not visible anywhere.

If you want to see a debugging web page related to a failing unit test, then do this.

1. Drop your development database.
2. Rerun `syncdb` to build an empty development database.
3. Run the various `loaddata` scripts to rebuild the fixtures for that test in your development database.
4. Run the server and browse the page.

Now you can see the debug output.

Comment: I realize that this is an older post, but a good reason to want `DEBUG=True` is to see messages from the tastypie REST api, which only show if both `DEBUG=True` and `TASTYPIE_FULL_DEBUG=True`.

Comment: Also when using selenium you do have the web pages displayed. One may want to see actual error messages should something not work right while building your tests.

Comment: Setting DEBUG=True also allows you to print generated SQL from ``django.db.connection.queries``, which can be helpful in crafting tests to cover strange edge cases.