# Disable "remember every SQL query" (Django)

Tags: django, django-orm

I know this:

> It is also important to remember that when running with DEBUG turned on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes. This is useful when you’re debugging, but it’ll rapidly consume memory on a production server.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug

I have a python script which does stress testing.

This script does *not* use the django test runner.

It uses the ORM in a loop doing more and more traffic in every iteration.

It would be great if my script could work in any environment.

I don't want other developers to force to fiddle with their settings (configure DEBUG  to False) before executing this script.

Is there a way to disable the particular feature "remember every SQL query"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set DEBUG to True when running a Django test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447134/how-do-you-set-debug-to-true-when-running-a-django-test)

Comment: here details [test-runner-options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#test-runner-options)

Comment: @BearBrown This script does *not* use the django test runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try monkey patching [`BaseDatabaseWrapper`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/76990cbbda5d93fda560c8a5ab019860f7efaab7/django/db/backends/base/base.py) to set `queries_limit` to zero. Otherwise you could have the script verify that debug is set to False, and if they try to use it with debug set to True, display a message informing them to run it with `DEBUG=False python manage.py script`.