# Django variable that is true when testing

Tags: python, django, testing

I want to have **a single** settings.py file that will behave differently when running the application

```
./manage.py runserver
```

and when testing

```
./manage.py test myapp
```

So, I can change the test db to sqlite for example, with something like:

```
if IS_TESTING:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
            'NAME': 'test_db',                      
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
            'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,                      
            'USER': DATABASE_USER,                      
            'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASS,                  
            'HOST': 'localhost',                      
            'PORT': '5432',                      
        }
    }
```

I can get this behaviour by changing the manage.py script like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault('IS_TESTING', 'false')
    print 'off'
    if sys.argv[1] == 'test':
        print 'on'
        os.environ['IS_TESTING'] = 'true'
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "frespo.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

But I think this is still not good enough, because when I run the tests inside an IDE (PyCharm) it won't use my custom manage.py file. There has to be a variable for this already inside Django. Do you know where it is?

Comment: Sounds very much like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088253/django-how-to-detect-test-environment

Comment: same solution indeed. sorry about that :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - how to detect test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088253/django-how-to-detect-test-environment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need this condition just for Django unit test purposes, the following line in the `settings.py` file should work:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False # if you're using south
```

This assumes the other standard `DATABASES` setting is always declared anyway. The above line simply sets the database to `sqlite` in case of a unit test run.

Comment: if DEBUG: 
 is a common useage.

Comment: @eusid You might find people who set `DEBUG=False` during unit tests to speed them up, example [here](http://www.daveoncode.com/2013/09/23/effective-tdd-tricks-to-speed-up-django-tests-up-to-10x-faster/).

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Django does not have such a variable. Assuming you can edit the exact command run by PyCharm, you could just add the test argument there, and then look for it in the settings.py file.

```
if "test-argument" in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
            'NAME': 'test_db',                      
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
            'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,                      
            'USER': DATABASE_USER,                      
            'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASS,                  
            'HOST': 'localhost',                      
            'PORT': '5432',                      
        }
    }
```