# Skipping code in python if in a unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

My current script calls an external script to perform some task. I want to check the code up to that point in a unittest, but not actually run the external script. Is there some way I can tell the script to effectively skip the following block IF the code is being run as part of a unit test?

Comment: Meaning you are importing the .py file you run in a unit test?

Comment: Mock out the external task and pass it as a parameter

Comment: Hmm. Haven't looked at Mock yet - probably should if I am going to do some proper unit testing.

Comment: You shouldn't have conditional test code mixed with production code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `unittest` package has extensive support for "mocking" functions and methods. Encapsulate the call to an external program in a simple function that your unit tests can override ("mock out") without modifying the structure of your program. Example:

Here is part of your program, in the module `realcode.py`

```
def internal_function_calling_exec(arg1):
    """The real thing"""
    print("I am executing an external program")


def bigger_function_being_tested(arg1, arg2):
    """
    A complex function with one or more calls to `internal_function_calling_exec`
    """
    print("I will now call `internal_function_calling_exec()`")
    internal_function_calling_exec(42)
```

Your unit test can then look like this:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import realcode

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("realcode.internal_function_calling_exec")
    def test_something(self, mocked_func):
        realcode.bigger_function_being_tested(1, 2)
        mocked_func.assert_called_with(42)
```

This will never call the original `internal_function_calling_exec()`. Instead, this will trigger a call to the mock object; your test can then query the object to confirm that it was called properly.

There are ways to mock class methods etc., so you could mock `subprocess.call` instead, for example. But I think the above is the better pattern.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to set an environment variable in the unit test, and check for that environment variable in the script being tested.

For example, in `unittest.py`:

```
os.environ["testing"] = "1"
```

And in `script-to-be-tested.py`:

```
testing = os.environ["testing"]
... do stuff based on the testing variable
```

Since `script-to-be-tested.py` will be called from `unittest.py`, it should inherit the environment variables.

Possibly not the cleanest solution, but it should work.

Comment: This was along the lines of what I was thinking. DI was wondering whether unittest set any itself that I could query?

Comment: @Chris: As far as I know pyunit itself doesn't change any environment variables. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25025987/4287999) for some other helpful solutions?