# Pydantic settings management + FastAPI: how to ignore a .env file during tests with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using [Pydantic settings management](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/) in a FastAPI-based project. I have a `Settings` class like this one:

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    FOO: str = ''
    BAR: int = 0

    class Config:
        env_file = "path/to/.my_env_file")
        env_nested_delimiter = "__"
```

The file `path/to/.my_env_file` contains `FOO` and `BAR` values.

During tests, I need to selectively patch `Settings`, and I do not want to read anything from `path/to/.my_env_file`. E.g.,

`path/to/.my_env_file`

```
FOO=i_do_not_wanna_read_this
BAR=100
```

my test file:

```
@lru_cache()
def get_settings():
    return Settings()

def get_settings_override() -> Settings:
    return Settings(
        FOO = 'foo'
    )

app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override
```

I want to run tests with `FOO='foo'` and with the default value of BAR (i.e., `BAR=0`, ignoring the content of `path/to/.my_env_file`. In the code above, I get `FOO='foo'` but `BAR` is still read from `path/to/.my_env_file` (i.e., `BAR=100`)

Is there a straightforward way to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't find a straightforward solution in the docs, or any other page, this worked for my tests:

When using tox, put this into your `tox.ini`, as per [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025928):

```ini
[testenv]
setenv = TOX_TESTENV = true
```

You can then simply use the following snippet to override your `env_file` settings:

```py
import os

# ... snip ...

if os.environ.get("TOX_TESTENV") is not None:
    Settings.Config.env_file = ""           # Pydantic 1.x
    Settings.model_config["env_file"] = ""  # Pydantic 2.x
```

Similar approaches, for example by checking `sys.argv` for the existence of "test" or checking [if `unittest` is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63742743), should work fine too:

```py
import sys

# ... snip ...

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and "pytest" in sys.argv[0]:
    Settings.Config.env_file = ""           # Pydantic 1.x
    Settings.model_config["env_file"] = ""  # Pydantic 2.x
```

---

Alternatively, here's a solution by [@hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling), utilizing [pytest hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html):

```py
def pytest_configure():
    Settings.Config.env_file = ""           # Pydantic 1.x
    Settings.model_config["env_file"] = ""  # Pydantic 2.x
```

Comment: Awesome, a custom hook `def pytest_configure(): Settings.Config.env_file = ''` did it for my test suite. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `monkeypatch` in a pytest fixture:

```py
import pytest

from app.settings import Settings


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def patch_settings_env_file_location(monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch) -> None:
    monkeypatch.setattr(Settings.Config, "env_file", "")
```

In this particular case, I've defined the `patch_settings_env_file_location` in the `conftest.py` located at the root folder of my tests.