# Unit-test: django.db.utils.OperationalError 1366 on startup

Tags: django, python-2.7, unit-testing, integration-testing, django-testing

It says `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD0\\xBD\\xD0\\xB0\\xD1\\x81...' for column 'name' at row 1")` when I try to start any of my unittests.

I bet this issue is caused by my DB charset, which is UTF-8, but I have no idea how to fix that.

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651002/5381547) answer to disable DB as a temporal solution, but I will need my DB in future.

Comment: did you tried use `unicode` function or use unicode literals?

Comment: @Baterson if you mean `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, it does not help

Comment: no, I just look at your traceback and decide something wrong with value of `name`, maybe you saving it from external file. without `unicode(name)`